# Token authentication not working django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I am using `token authentication` for my current project but I have one problem, I can not authenticate a use for the life of me. To test my authentication I created a `superuser` and then the command `python manage.py drf_create_token test1`. And then created this view:

```
class HelloView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated)

    def get(self, request):
        content = {'message': 'Hello, World!'}
        return Response(content)
```

In my `setting.py file` I have:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ... # ...
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'backend',
    'frontend'
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
}
```

And when I test my API I keep geting:

```
{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}
```

What am I missing here? can anyone tell me? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use token authentication, then you must send token in all request to server in headers. So, you header request should contain the following entry:

[image]

Comment: You make yourself very clear, one problem though see I am new to token authentication and do not know how to do this, if you could provide me a code sample i would be very thankful.

Comment: But if you don't have the time could you at least tell me where can I learn how to do this(resources for learning how to do this)

Comment: here is clear described https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/11/22/how-to-implement-token-authentication-using-django-rest-framework.html

Comment: thank you very much for your time and effort, I finaly solved my problem